# Small and fast Unicode character picker with support for TeX math

Tags: open-source, latex, unicode

Sometimes I need simple Unicode math characters (like `α≠β`) quickly inserted into any text field. Since I'm very used to LaTeX it's very convenient for me find these through their equivalent (La)TeX commands. I often open Emacs and do `set-input-method tex`, and type in the TeX commands for the symbols (like `\alpha\neq\beta` in the above example) and copy-paste the resulting Unicode characters.

That works, but I'd like a more streamlined solution. Is there some fast, minimalistic little piece of software that lets me:

- Quickly do the above
- Also search for other Unicode characters through their descriptions (like "man shrugging" → ‍♂️), preferably interactively being shown suitable results

Requirements: FOSS, GNU/Linux-compatible, Wayland-native if GUI-based

Comment: Whether any such Unicode picker can be "small" is questionable. The Unicode database alone is ~40 MB, AFAIK.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Hah, fair enough! I should have been more clear. By "small" I rather meant properties like "does precisely the above, and nothing / not much else" and "doesn't come bundled with a goddamn web browser engine or the likes". Thanks for the comment.